# JsonSerializationException from TFS REST API response

Tags: c#, tfs, json.net, azure-devops, tfs-sdk

I am trying to use the new TFS/VSTS REST APIs with our on-prem TFS 2015 server, and cannot retrieve test runs as the response fails internal validation.

Using client code like the following:

```
var connection = new VssConnection(serverUri), credentials);
var client = connection.GetClient<TestManagementHttpClient>();
var runs = await client.GetTestRunsAsync("project", planId:183110);
```

throws a `JsonSerializationException` in line 3 with the following message:

```
Required property 'environmentName' not found in JSON. Pathvalue[0].testEnvironment', line 1, position 582.
```

which is accurate. Checking the response in Fiddler shows that the `testEnvironment` property only has an `environmentId` property, no `name`. I have uploaded a trimmed sample of the response to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/agc93/88cd2b0747981094731f477fa9e6e015).

My question is why does TFS not return this value or alternatively, is there a way to force the API SDK to ignore this validation error?

Comment: Do you vote that feedback and achieve your requirement with my workaround?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! That workaround did the job, and the responses are coming back now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce that issue if includeRunDetails parameter is true. I reported a bug [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3102967) that you can vote it.

The workaround is that you could set includeRunDetails to false to get test runs without details include, then base on the result (test run id) to get a test run with details that you want.

```
client.GetTestRunByIdAsync
```